# Problem deserializing and object using json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

USing json.net to deserialize json to a list. My issue is that I am getting the following message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'data', line 1, position 9.'

My code looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>> (response.Content.ToString());
```

and...

```
internal class Projects
{
    internal object id;
    internal string gid;
    internal string name;
    internal string resource_type;
}
```

response.Content.ToString() looks like this:

> {     "data": [{      "id": 123456,       "gid": "789",       "name": "Tooling -
>   Start tool",      "resource_type": "project"  }, {        "id": 123456,
>         "gid": "789",       "name": "Hold for Details",         "resource_type":
>   "project"     }] }

My json validates. I am certain that it is the formatting of the json but I do not understand enough to understand what is wrong. What is wrong with my approach? How do I get this formatted data to concert to a List of Projects?

Comment: You have a root object with a collection of `Projects` not a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: You can also have `var obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ToString())["data"];`, then `var projects = obj.ToObject<List<Projects>>();`. You need to use **properties**, not fields, which need to be **`public`**. Also `id` and `gid` should be `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JSON, there's some root object ("data"), so your model should look like this:

```cs
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string gid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string resource_type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Project> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then for parsing your code also changes:

```cs
var JSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

I'd also suggest thinking for a second about class name - your class is actually only one `Project`, not any group/collection of `Projects`. 

Also setting type of `id` to `object` looks like adding unnecessary overhead - it can be simply `int`/`long`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and worked. I agree about Projects vs Project as well. Thanks for pointing that out.